# Javascript to change the text of the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am a very new to Javascript. now I have a dropdown list within django.
        
        
            ---Select a status---

ALL

Expired

Pending

if I select give "ALL" as an example, it would navigate to "/all/" page, this is the correct behavior, but how can I change the text  to "ALL" ?

Comment: Add this as Onclick event or user any other event listener 
document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = "yournewtext";
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="dropdown1" class="dropdown filter" >
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="placeholder">---Select A Status---</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a class="active" href={{ view_all }}>All</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href={{ view_exipred }}>Expired</a></li>
        <li><a class="" href={{ view_pending }}>Pending</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Sorry for the incorrect edit.above are the code here.

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded here?

Comment: you should edit your question and add this code instead or posting it as an answer.

Comment: @taxicala, thank you, trying to edit it, but did not find the edit link.